# Problem with the IR receiver

Tags: ir-receiver

I have two V38238 IR receiver's but one acts as active low and other as active high. What could be the reason? Is there a difference in the part number?( both had 69 DRZD V38238 specified on it ) I am using the following IR receiver circuit. I checked both the receiver's using the same circuit. [image: IR remote Receiver]

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a tsop symbol like the one you have posted. However, unless your tsop is damaged, you might be doing it wrong. (Also, provide a link to the datasheet when you ask a question.)

Here is the mechanical drawing from the datasheet:

[image: TSOP]

And this is the circuit from the datasheet that you should use:

[image: TSOP circuit]

R1 = 33 ohm to 1 kohm

C1 > 0.1 uF

Also, the output can be directly connected to a micro-controller. You have made a voltage divider. You should try getting rid of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it without the voltage divider, but the receivers are still acting the same. One is acting as active low and other as active high. I have been using the receivers since long and both have different behaviour.